# Server log - duration calculation with Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I’m new to Spark had a question about calculating duration. I have a server log with a IP address and server connection time (date time field). I am trying to calculate the duration between connectivity times for each record in the log. I’m able to filter down the set and format all the data I need, but I don’t know how to compare the values between two different rows for a given IP address.

Here is what my set looks like.

```
IP  Activity
235.325.23.22, 2014-09-01 03:31
235.325.23.22, 2014-09-01 03:39
235.325.23.22, 2014-09-01 03:43
235.325.23.22, 2014-09-01 03:46
235.325.23.22, 2014-09-01 03:55
235.423.25.44, 2014-09-01 17:21
235.423.25.44, 2014-09-01 17:30
235.423.25.44, 2014-09-01 17:34
235.423.25.44, 2014-09-01 17:42
235.423.25.44, 2014-09-01 17:51
```

I would like to get the following result:

```
235.325.23.22, 2014-09-01 03:31am,0 base--start of the 235.325.23.22 IP set
235.325.23.22, 2014-09-01 03:39am,8 minutes
235.325.23.22, 2014-09-01 03:43am,4 minutes
235.325.23.22, 2014-09-01 03:46am,3 minutes
235.325.23.22, 2014-09-01 03:55am,9 minutes
235.423.25.44, 2014-09-01 17:21pm,0 base-- start of the new 235.423.25.44 IP set
235.423.25.44, 2014-09-01 17:30pm,9 minutes
235.423.25.44, 2014-09-01 17:34pm,4 minutes
235.423.25.44, 2014-09-01 17:42pm,8 minutes
235.423.25.44, 2014-09-01 17:51pm,9 minutes
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer but direction:

let's call your initial set rdd, such that it is an rdd keyed on IP with the datetime string as value.

Use val sortedRDD = rdd.repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(new HashPartitioner(numPartitions)) to create a sorted partition per key (pick numPartitions to be much larger than your keys). 
Then use mapPartitions on the sortedRDD -- you'll get a sorted iterator, so really you just need to keep track of the previous value and subtract as you go.
In a very lazy attempt something like

```
sortedRDD.mapPartitions(iter=>{ var prev=""; iter.map{i=>val t =(i._1,i._2,if (prev=="") 0 else prev);prev=i._2;t}})
```

(I did not do the difference and did not parse dates but hopefully this helps you out with the idea)